# Writing JSP in kotlin with maven - Error instantiating servlet class, ClassNotFoundException

Tags: maven, jsp, tomcat, kotlin

so I've been trying out JSP for some time now, and I want to use it with kotlin and maven, I'm having some problems,

It throws ClassNotFoundException, here is my files:

- [web.xml](https://pastebin.com/XkzdhLj0)

  ```
  <web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
      <servlet>
          <servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name>
          <servlet-class>com.erezbiox1.Servlet</servlet-class>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
  </web-app>
  ```
- [pom.xml](https://pastebin.com/EVKHfcGc)

  ```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.erezbiox1</groupId>
    <artifactId>KotlinJsp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>KotlinJsp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
      </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
      <finalName>KotlinJsp</finalName>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
          <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.0</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>compile</id>
              <phase>compile</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
  </project>
  ```
- [Servlet.kt](https://pastebin.com/LB0aJ7cd)

  ```
  // Tried with, and without this:
  @file:JvmName("Servlet")

  package com.erezbiox1

  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse

  class Servlet : HttpServlet(){

  override fun doGet(req: HttpServletRequest, resp: HttpServletResponse) {
      resp.writer.println("<h1>IT WORKS!</h1>")
      resp.writer.flush()
  }

  }
  ```

and here is the project structure:
[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTtcp.png)

here is the [error](https://pastebin.com/B3tsWzy3):

```
// Exception:

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class com.erezbiox1.Servlet
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

// Root Cause:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.erezbiox1.Servlet
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Is it even possible? both jsp, kotlin and maven?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not quite familiar but why is your class in `resources`? I don't think that's the right location

Comment: @1blustone because of maven I'm pretty sure.

Comment: @1blustone when I created the project, the resource folder was exactly where the src folder was in my previous jsp projects, and the project had no src folders, so I've just assumed it's there.  [this is the project's structure now](https://i.imgur.com/PS9hOpF.png), and it works!, post this as an answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classes in your project are in the `resources` folder.

This is not where they should be - this folder is used only for resources.

Create a new folder, mark it as source root, and use that folder instead.